# Get an Image that is the child of a Panel

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a panel and I added it in a Window as ItemsPanel of an ItemsControl

```
<Grid x:Name="outerGrid" >
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageSourcesCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <view:CustomPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

As you can see in this panel I show a series of images. Everything works all right, but now I want to access those images from inside the CustomPanel to change the Source to one of them.

If I access them as elements of base.Children I obtain a ContentPresenter, i.e.:

```
var element = base.Children[i]; //<- this is a ContentPresenter
```

So my question is: how can I get the Image?

One solution, since I know the position of the image, would be to get the element at that position. But I would prefer something else because it is not really clean and if I have other images moving around it can be a source of troubles.

Thanks!

Comment: No fully sure what you intend to do. If you can already display your images why don't you just fetch the images again from the `ImageSourcesCollection`?

Comment: Because what I showed here is a part of the xaml of the Window. ImageSourceCollection is in the ViewModel of the Window and I want to access them in the panel... sorry I will change the question since it was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if you just want to change the source of the Image (and this was my case), you can change the property Content of the ContentPresenter. Not sure how to access the Image though...